# How to get Text or Button to register click events on top of an Expo map?

Tags: react-native, button, click, maps, expo

I am trying to have clickable text or a button on top of my Expo maps. My provider is google, and when I try to render text that is clickable on top of my maps it fails. The text shows up, but does not register click events. Any ideas? 
Here is some code: (see at the bottom I am loading  Return to home. )

```
     <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: HOMESCREEN_BACKGROUND}}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle="light-content" />
        <View style={styles.topBar}>
            <Text style={styles.cityText}>
                {this.state.city}, {this.state.region}
            </Text>
            <Text style={styles.usernameText}>
              {this.props.user.uid}
            </Text>
        </View>
        <MapView 
            ref={this.map}
            style={styles.map}  provider="google" customMapStyle={NIGHT_MAP_STYLE}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: this.props.reduxMap.latitude,
              longitude: this.props.reduxMap.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: this.props.reduxMap.latitudeDelta,
              longitudeDelta: this.props.reduxMap.longitudeDelta,
          }}
          showsScale={true}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          onChange={(event) => this.handleMapViewChange(event)}
        >             

          {/* {this.renderRelevantQueues()} */}
          <Text style={styles.returnToHome} onPress={this.snapMapViewToUser} >Return to home</Text>
        </MapView>
        <View style={styles.bottomBar}>
            <Text style={styles.backText} onPress={() => this.handleBackButtonClicked()}>
                Back
            </Text>
            {this.renderReturnToCurrentLocationSvg()}
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

In response to some questions about this post.

1. You can see the text, but you can't click it?

   - I can see a button or text or really whatever on top of the map. However, the click event is not firing when I physically click on the element.
2. what does renderReturnToCurrentLocationSvg doing ? does it render view or image that might be infront of your text layer?

   - This is actually commented out in my code but it renders a series of pins and radiuses around them on the map from a database. Removed the function and the issue still persists.
3. Can you add styles of current screen?
   Yes, here they are:

   ```
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: HOMESCREEN_BACKGROUND
   },
   topBar: {
     height: 200,
     backgroundColor: HOMESCREEN_BACKGROUND,
   },
   map: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column'
   },
   returnToHome: {
      color: 'white',
      position: 'absolute',
      fontSize: 30,
      marginLeft: '30%'
   },
   createQueue: {
     color: 'white',
     marginLeft: '50%',
     fontSize: 30
   },
   loadingTxt: {
     textAlign: 'center', 
     fontSize: 18,
     marginTop: "100%",
     marginLeft: "25%",
     width: 200
   },
   topBar: {
     height: '10%',
     backgroundColor: HOMESCREEN_BACKGROUND,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
     borderBottomColor: 'grey',
     borderBottomWidth: 1
   },
   bottomBar: {
     height: '10%',
     backgroundColor:  HOMESCREEN_BACKGROUND,
     flexDirection: 'row',
     borderTopColor: 'grey',
     borderTopWidth: 1,
   },
   backText: {
     color: 'white',
     fontSize: 30,
     marginLeft: 0
   },
   cityText: {
     color: 'white',
     fontSize: 30,
   },
   usernameText: {
    color: 'grey'
   }
   });
   ```

Comment: You can see the text, but you can't click it?

Comment: what does renderReturnToCurrentLocationSvg doing ? does it render view or image that might be infront of your text layer?

Comment: can you add styles of current screen?